# How to add a Scroll to Top button on welcome page with web part zone?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I want the scroll to top button at the bottom right corner of the page but not within a web part zone. I'm not very good at html either and have found sources that kinda help me but they all mention adding CSS and jquery which I know nothing about.. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very functional [w3schools demo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_to_top) ( which is the source of this answer )

This is the styles part, which goes to `btnstyle.css`

```
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

This is the javscript part which goes into either a script editor or a file `ScrollButton.js`

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Have a content editor webpart, with the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<path>/btnstyle.css">
 </head>
<body>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
<script src="<path>/ScrollButton.js"
</body>
</html>
```

Try this out and let me know if you are still facing issues :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it scroll to top on every page, than you need to put following code in master page within div having id `s4-bodyContainer`. For a single page you can put the code in `content editor web part`. (Code provided below)

Also, the simplest solution we can provide will require at least HTML knowledge. No need of CSS and JS/JQ. CSS is used to make it beautiful whereas JS and JQ provide high level of scrolling.

Just put a paragraph as first child of s4-bodyContainer (for all pages) or add a content editor web part as the first web part on a page and write following HTML.

```
<p id="topOfPage" style="visibility: hidden; height: 1px;">To of Page </p>
<a href="#topOfPage" style="position: fixed; right: 20px; bottom: 20px">Scroll To Top</a>
```

This is it. You will have a hyperlink at the bottom to scroll to top of page. You can apply CSS to hyperlink i.e. `<a>` tag to look good as per your design.